# Rename Files during Extraction (Zip) process ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, zip, radupload

i have a RadUpload that uploads zip file only,
so i want to rename the each file during Extraction Process,
i tried a way :

```
Protected Sub Upload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim extractPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/temp/")
    Dim file1 As String = RadUpload1.UploadedFiles(0).FileName

    ExtractFileToDirectory(file1, extractPath)

End Sub

Public Sub ExtractFileToDirectory(zipFileName As String, outputDirectory As String)

    Dim zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(outputDirectory & zipFileName)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory)
    For Each e As ZipEntry In zip

        Dim NewName As String = Now().ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss")
        Dim newext As String = ".jpg"
        e.FileName = NewName + newext

        e.Extract(outputDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
    Next
End Sub
```

at the first it will rename and extract the first file but then gives this error:

[ It has been adjusted Group: Could not execute the census process. ]

any idea?

Comment: Could you not just rename the file after a successful extraction?

Comment: yea i want to rename after successful extraction of all files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with `outputDirectory`

```
Dim zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(outputDirectory & zipFileName)
Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory)
```

In the first line you are trying to read `outputDirectory & zipFileName`, in the second line you are trying to create that path.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.openread(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2), your code should be similar to

```
Using zip As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileName)
   For Each e As ZipArchiveEntry In zip.Entries

     Dim NewName As String = Now().ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss")
     Dim newext As String = ".jpg"
     NewName += newext
     e.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(outputDirectory, NewName ))

   Next
 End Using
```

NOTE: Using `"ddMMyyhhmmss"` as a file name you most likely will get an error if unzip takes less than 1 sec - either add ms, i.e. `"ddMMyyhhmmssfff"` or check if file name does not exist before extract.

Comment: exactly what i want but when i copy your code it says ZipArchive in not Recognized

Comment: i also added this reference [ Imports System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive ] but does not accept the reference

Comment: after i changed framework version to 4.5 then your code worked like a charm , thanks for your help, you saved my day

Comment: If you want to keep old .net version, you can still use your old code but you should change the behaviour of using outputDirectory

Comment: This works great! I was having issues extracting a file with too long of a name so this allowed me to rename it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting to extract to a "temp" folder, you really should be using the System temporary folder. Writing data inside your web app is a bad practice.

Use the following to retrieve the system-defined temporary folder

```
Private Sub Upload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

Dim extractPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() ' Better way to store temporary files
Dim file1 As String = RadUpload1.UploadedFiles(0).FileName

ExtractFileToDirectory(file1, extractPath)

End Sub
```

Then inside ExtractFileToDirectory function you create a brand new temporary folder (use [Guid.NewGuid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Guid.NewGuid);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).ToString() to generate a unique folder name) and unzip files as explained by @2316116, using the [ExtractToFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485718(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Following this approach saves you from nasty errors occurring when multiple zip files are unpacking at the very same time.

Comment: your code just extracts the zip , i want to rename  each file in the zip during extraction

Comment: Mine was an improvement suggestion to @2316116 answer, since using DateTime for name uniqueness is not bulletproof, and writing files into Web App folder is a bad practice.